# Issue converting date format from a data frame to timeserie

Tags: r, rstudio

I found this code online:

```
#Integration and co-integration analysis of equity indexes.
library(urca)
library(vars)
## Loading data set and converting to zoo
data(EuStockMarkets)

Assets=as.zoo(EuStockMarkets)

## Aggregating as month’s−enddput series

AssetsM=aggregate(Assets , as.yearmon ,  tail , 1)
head(AssetsM)

## Applying unit root tests for sub−sample

AssetsMsub=window( AssetsM,start =start( AssetsM ), end = "Jun 1996")

# class = "yearmon"), class = c("zooreg", "zoo"), frequency = 12)

## Levels

ADF=lapply(AssetsMsub,ur.df,type = "drift",selectlags = "AIC")
```

With the EuStockMarkets data details here:

> Description
>
> Contains the daily closing prices of major European stock indices:
>   Germany DAX (Ibis), Switzerland SMI, France CAC, and UK FTSE. The data
>   are sampled in business time, i.e., weekends and holidays are omitted.
>   Usage
>
> EuStockMarkets
>
> Format
>
> A multivariate time series with 1860 observations on 4 variables. The
>   object is of class "mts".

I try to use my own data which are in a data.frame format. As the first column is a date vector with mixed format I use a standard format.

```
dput datetest2 = ow.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

But I have an issue with the last line of the code:

```
#Integration and co-integration analysis of equity indexes.
library(urca)
library(vars)

## Loading data set and converting to zoo
rm(list = setdiff(ls(), lsf.str()))

datetest2 <- read.csv("~/Desktop/datetest2.csv")

## As date aren't in uniformised format we create a date vector and replace the old one

DateTS <-as.Date(as.Date("2017/10/02"):as.Date("2018/05/22"), origin="1970/01/01") 
datetest2[,1]=DateTS

## Convert data frame to c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))

data <- ts(datetest2[,-1],start=datetest2[1,1],end=datetest2[NROW(datetest2),1],frequency = 1 )

Assets=as.zoo(data)

## Aggregating as month’s−end series

AssetsM=Assets
AssetsM=aggregate(Assets , as.yearmon ,  tail , 1)
head(AssetsM)

## Applying unit root tests for sub−sample

AssetsMsub=window(AssetsM,start =start( AssetsM ), end = end(AssetsM))

## Levels

ADF=lapply(AssetsMsub,ur.df,type = "drift",selectlags = "AIC")
```

this error: Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

But it's not clear to me as the Date are already in an unambiguous format, any idea?

```
> dput(head(datetest2,10))
structure(list(X = structure(c(17441, 17442, 17443, 17444, 17445, 
17446, 17447, 17448, 17449, 17450), class = "Date"),X1 = c(0.001266303, 
-0.021048584, -0.020621217, 0.023149588, 0.009748078, 0.012748959, 
0.040634667, 0.034437722, 0.002087083, 0.009260646), X2 = c(0.037842672, 
-0.219755806, 0.052179239, -0.020359985, -0.147664555, 0.121832339, 
-0.022406655, 0.076908587, -0.026717135, 0.044910046), X3 = c(-0.022771565, 
-0.0411676, 0.030648901, -0.000196444, 0.004834399, 0.011694903, 
-0.026136535, -0.064203569, 0.026439081, 0.024184196), X4 = c(-0.016205216, 
-0.017019091, 0.00068362, 0.010874844, 0.042127166, 0.008165155, 
-0.008100346, -0.037033935, 0.008304639, 0.011900759), X5 = c(-0.058696937, 
-0.024072712, -0.026573368, -0.011153745, -0.07178172, 0.067360919, 
-0.074169252, -0.063135862, 0.017187075, 0.008108153), X6 = c(-0.021498233, 
-0.019484207, -0.018313765, 0.00523917, 0.00867141, 0.008787067, 
0.010594121, -0.057712044, 0.011102414, 0.00334613), X7 = c(-0.018186256, 
0.015393258, -0.027814412, 0.015910798, -0.007320437, 0.005577137, 
-0.021271535, -0.048851434, 0.0154376, 0.00688708), X8= c(-0.061737994, 
-0.038319809, -0.019420551, -0.034385314, 0.001193193, 0.004084886, 
-0.085468062, 0.000636325, 0.074028454, 0.023084468), X9= c(0.028155324, 
-0.089042438, -0.075688421, 0.035312622, 0.037694432, 0.07525801, 
-0.119479271, -0.09718284, 0.007190581, 0.021934404), X10 = c(-0.054497537, 
-0.044083621, -0.045526127, 0.206964088, 0.233137354, 0.130054454, 
-0.1195141, -0.055098329, 0.074006512, 0.02588484)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please dput - datetest2 . It's difficult to help without the actual dataset.

Comment: row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") here is the dput

Comment: You didn't copy the all dput. Maybe I wasn't clear. I'm interested at how your csv file looks like. For example, dput for the first two lines of mtcars (data from tidyverse package) looks like this > dput(mtcars[1:2,])
structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(6, 6), disp = c(160, 
160), hp = c(110, 110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9), wt = c(2.62, 2.875
), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02), vs = c(0, 0), am = c(1, 1), gear = c(4, 
4), carb = c(4, 4)), .Names = c("mpg", "cyl", "disp", "hp", "drat", 
"wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: dput(head(datetest2,2))
structure(list(X = structure(c(17441, 17442), class = "Date"), 
    X1 = c(0.001266303, -0.021048584), X2 = c(0.037842672, 
    -0.219755806), X2 = c(-0.022771565, -0.0411676), X3= c(-0.016205216, 
    -0.017019091), X4 = c(-0.058696937, -0.024072712), X5= c(-0.021498233, 
    -0.019484207), X6= c(-0.018186256, 0.015393258), X7 = c(-0.061737994, 
    -0.038319809), X8= c(0.028155324, -0.089042438), X9= c(-0.054497537, 
    -0.044083621)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")  Is it better like that ? sorry i'm not sure to understand well

Comment: It's much better. However, it's only first two rows. Could you provide a bit more?. In addition, I tried running your code line by line, it seems like you have a lot of bugs a long the way...

Comment: Thank you for your help , i added the first 10 lines. The idea is to convert my data exactly as the data of Eurostocks, using my code it's was i thought would be working but it didn't.